# How do I save an adjusted d3.js visualization?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm a noob and have been copying and altering d3.js scripts for hands on learning. I copied 
robschmuecker’s (block #7880033 December 09, 2013)
D3.js Drag and Drop, Zoomable, Panning, Collapsible Tree with auto-sizing http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033

and would like to know: 
a) how I can save the Tree after I have re-arranged it?
b) if after re-arranging it can it save as a different file (original would be version 1, re-arranged would be version 2) 
c) how to make it also save new .json file with re-arranged parent children?
(think they might all be the same question.)

Any help or advice would push me in the right direction. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

In the code you have root variable. It represents actual tree structure with additional fields like: "x", "x0", "y", "y0", "id" ...
To get rid of this additional fields you can use this function:

```
var delAdditionalFilds = function(obj) {

  for (var prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      if (prop === 'name' || prop === 'children' || prop === 'size') {} else {
        delete obj[prop];
      }
    }
  }
  if (obj.children) {
    obj.children.forEach(function(v, i) {
      delAdditionalFilds(v);
    });
  }

};
```

To avoid overwriting original object you should make deep copy of root variable. I use lodash library to do that.

So, save function will 
1) prepare deep copy of root object and then 2) get rid of additional fields

```
var save = function(root) {
  var newJSON = _.copy(root);
  delAdditionalFilds(newJSON);
  // now you can send newJSON to your server
};
```

After this operation you will have JSON object ready to send to your server using ajax call